# optimise a mysql query to reduce rows searched

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I'm currently grabbing the last 5 comments posted on my website, which I am seemingly doing quite badly I think.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT c.comment_id
     , c.article_id
     , c.time_posted
     , a.title
     , a.slug
     , u.username
  FROM articles_comments c 
  JOIN articles a 
    ON c.article_id = a.article_id 
  JOIN users u 
    ON u.user_id = c.author_id 
 WHERE a.active = 1 
   AND c.approved = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY c.comment_id DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

My problem, is that has to search through a lot of rows, it seems quite wasteful. I'm curious if there's a better way to do it.

Here's the output of explain on it:
[image]

As you can see, the rows it's giving is 81,486 which seems kind of hilarious. What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe this can help: https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: If you need to just grab the last 5 comments, why do you need to `JOIN` with `articles` AND `users` tables?

Comment: @Eric so it can display the article name the comment is on and the username of the person who commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, simply forcing articles_comments to use the PRIMARY key (comment_id) as the INDEX fixed it.

The issue is that my sorting is picking ALL approved comments, so it was using the approved column to sort resulting in it picking data from tens of thousands.

Comment: Another consideration for future.  You have Time_Posted.  If you have a bunch of activity, you could even shorten even more by adding … AND Time_Posted > 2 days ago...  unless a very low-volume site, you know your activity... then it would not have to go back too far either (provided time post was an index option too).  Also look into MySQL "STRAIGHT_JOIN" clause which tells engine... do the query in the exact order I have laid-out.  Don't guess my join conditions for optimum processing.

Comment: Didn't know about STRAIGHT_JOIN, much appreciated! Will keep that in mind too.

Answer (score 0):

```
c:  INDEX(approved, comment_id)  -- in this order
a:  I assume you have PRIMARY KEY(article_id)
u:  I assume you have PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
```

The hope is that the `c` index will handle some of the `WHERE`, plus the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  The worst case is that it must scan the entire table without finding 5 rows.

The 81,486 is bogus.  Here's a precise way to get good info:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

The 'reads' will indicate how many rows of data and index were touched; the writes indicate temp table(s) being used.